# odoo 8 Forms missing attachments combo box

Tags: odoo

I have installed odoo8 on Debian Jessie using the [following Tutorial](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2014/09/how-to-install-openerp-odoo-8-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts/). It works fine except one thing:

- The **attachment combo box** is not visible on the pages where it should
  be (quotes, invoices, etc.). I only have the **"Print"** and **"Other
  Options"** Combos.

I did not find any information in the docs, anyOne had this issue already ?
Thanks,

Comment: Did you install the "Knowledge" module and add rights to it?

Comment: @dccdany, you are Great, this is the answer.

Comment: added it as an answer glad i could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the "Knowledge" module and add rights to it :).

Comment: There is no module "Knowledge" in v10 or v11 is there any alternative?